# How to create modifier for admin customer form in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, customer-attribute, magento2.4.1

I have created a new virtualType to change newly added customer attribute value in customer form. But I am unable to modify attribute data.

What is wrong with the below code?

[image]

Comment: Stuck at the same level, but what's incompatible is the argument the documentation wants us to inject into the data provider (pool) and the `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\DataProvider`constructor, shame ... it would've been a good way

Comment: possible connection with this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142867/51034)

Comment: @Mahammad did you get any answer in this because I am also stuck in same issue/