# How to add custom checkout fileds fetched from DB?

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, knockoutjs

How can I make a new, custom, checkout fields fetched from DB?

I have created a new table where I keep fields names, also I created a Model, Resources, ResourceModel (admin can modify or add new one fileds in admin panel) to this entity - what I want to do now is to pass this data as a custom radio options to checkout (Something similar to Shipping Methods). What should I do to achive it?

So far I have:
custom-checkout-form.js
custom-checkout-form.html
checkout_index_index.xml files (like in this tutorial: https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/add-new-input-form-to-checkout-in-magento-2/) but I still don't know how to get my fields from my custom DB table

Update - I see some examples about select options eg. [How to setdata for field in form UI](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142867/how-to-setdata-for-field-in-form-ui) but still digging about radios